# Relative minus sign Feynman Diagrams from spin statistics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, spin-statistics

I am having trouble understanding whether there should be a minus sign between the two Feynmann diagrams contributing to second order in $\phi \psi \to \phi \psi $ scattering, in Yukawa theory.

I have done the full calculation the long way (Wick's Theorem, etc) and I seem to get a relative minus sign. This would be consistent with fermionic statistics (under the exchange of the initial and final fermion). However, wouldn't this violate bosonic statistics for the scalar? (Under the exchange of the initial and final boson, the amplitude should remain unchanged).

I have seen a few similar questions, but I don't think they help me understand the signs here. In particular, for nucleon-antinucleon scattering (Bhabha scattering if electrons and positrons), there is a relative minus sign that is consistent with fermionic statistics (and I understand it here). However, in Compton scattering $\gamma+ e- \to \gamma + e-$ there is no relative sign: this is okay with bosonic statistics for the photons, but not for the fermionic statistics of the electron.

Comment: Suggestion: Consider to include the relevant Feynman diagrams.